# RF Direction Finding

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, rfid, radio

Is it possible to build a system with a raspberry pi and antennas to find the rough direction of a radio frequency emitter such as a Wifi router, a Bluetouth Tag, or, a 5G cell tower?

I cannot use distant antennas to use triangulation. If several antennas are needed, they should be close (within 50cm) from each other.

From wikipedia, it seems that such a system is possible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_finding

Comment: Yes it is possible. Systems have been built with [Bluetooth](https://medium.com/supplyframe-hardware/bluetooth-indoor-positioning-and-asset-tracking-solutions-8c78cae0a03) on the RPi.  A simple setup can [Inferring distance](https://medium.com/personaldata-io/inferring-distance-from-bluetooth-signal-strength-a-deep-dive-fe7badc2bb6d) from Bluetooth signal strength. If there are multiple receivers or transmitters then [trilateration](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2017/03/13/positioning-and-trilateration/) can be used.

Answer (score 2):

@ukBaz is correct, but your question may be considered "off-topic" here - despite the fact that `radio` is an "approved" tag (close voters take note).

But as a *practical* matter, you're far more likely to find helpful information and "how-to" guidance somewhere else; e.g. the [GNU radio project](https://www.gnuradio.org/), and [Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/). Or perhaps [Amateur Radio SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?q=direction+finder)